# Is there an implementation of SQL-like data access for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, object

I'm hoping to graph some data I have in an object in Javascript and the first thing that comes to mind is using an SQL-like interface to get the organized data on that object via a query. I've searched around the web and found nothing but an [entire sqlite implementation in JS](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js), when I'm just looking for an easier way to access information that's in a Javascript object.

Since this thing doesn't seem like an idea with much interest, I was wondering if any of you stackoverflow folks have written or heard of such a library. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. How can you make accessing object fields easier? It's a basic language construct.

Comment: Object-oriented databases like MongoDB do that.

Comment: I'm getting my data from CouchDB, [queries look like they require an amount of setup](http://sitr.us/2009/06/30/database-queries-the-couchdb-way.html) and don't have the ease of SQL

Comment: There are things like [this object graph tool](http://jsog.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe YQL?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

You can define different data sources. I haven't tried it with "in-memory" JavaScript objects though.